# Prove that the minimum of row sums of a nonnegative symmetric matrix is preserved

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ adjacency (nonnegative, irreducible and symmetric) matrix with zeros on the diagonal. Denote $i$-th row sum of $A^k$ as $r^{(k)}_i$, where $k\geq1$. I want to prove that if $r_j=r_{j'}=\min_i\{r_i\}$ for some $j$ and $j'$ and $r_m=c>r_j$ when $m\neq j$ and $m\neq j'$ for some constant $c$, then $r^{(k)}_j=min_i\{r^{(k)}_i\}$, in other words the minimum row sum is preserved.

I know that this is true only based on intuition. For example, consider a graph in which two vertices, say vertex 1 and vertex 2 without loss of generality, in a graph have degree $r-1$ and the remaining $n-2$ vertices have degree $r$, where $2\leq r\leq n-1$. One should see the number of walks of length $k$ starting from vertex 1 or vertex 2 is smaller than the number of walks of the same length but with a starting point other than vertex 1 and veretx 2. It would be much appreciated if someone can provide some idea for a formal proof.